# How to solve implementation problem in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I need to solve an equation, but spider returns me this error:

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy as sympy
Re=100
Epsilon=0.00000075
D=0.01
f=symbols('f')
eq=(((1/(-2* sympy.log((Epsilon/D/ 3.7)+( 2.51 / (Re*(f**0.5))), 10)))**2 -f),0)
sym.solve((eq), (f))
print(f)
    
    NotImplementedError: could not solve -4*f*log(202702702702703/10000000000000000000 + 251/(10000*sqrt(f)))**2 + log(10)**2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `solve` function is for finding analytic solutions but that isn't possible for your equation (not all equations have analytic solutions):

```
In [11]: eq[0]
Out[11]: 
                         2                     
                      log (10)                 
-f + ──────────────────────────────────────────
          2⎛        -0.5                      ⎞
     4⋅log ⎝0.0251⋅f     + 2.02702702702703e-5⎠
```

You can find a numeric solution with `nsolve`:

```
In [12]: sym.nsolve(eq[0], f, 0.1)
Out[12]: 0.169438052045717
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve

Answer (score 1):

This can be represented in terms of the LambertW function, but it needs some help. SymPy doesn't recognize the inverted `sqrt(f)` in the `log`. If you replace that with `1/y` and solve for `y` and transform the solutions for `y` back to `f` you can get a symbolic solution.

It's easier in this case to let SymPy work with symbols instead of Floats and substitute the values later. Your equation looks like this:

```
>>> from sympy import a,b,c
>>> seq = a**2/log(b/sqrt(f) + c)**2 - f
>>> reps = {a:log(10)/2, c:Epsilon/D/3.7, b:2.51/Re}
```

Replace that `sqrt(f)` with `1/y`

```
>>> ysol = solve(seq.xreplace(sqrt(f), 1/y), y)
```

Calculate the corresponding solutions for `f`:

```
>>> fsol = [((1/i)**2) for i in ysol]
```

Substitute in your values -- or any values that you are interested in:

```
>>> [i.xreplace(reps).n(3) for i in fsol]
[0.00771 - 0.107*I, 0.169]
```

Testing in the original shows that the second solution is valid

```
>>> [eq.subs(f,i).n() for i in _]
[0.148289010493944 + 0.206688429851791*I, 6.05179945288758e-6]
```

So your symbolic solution is

```
>>> fsol[1]
(-c/b + LambertW(a*exp(a*c/b)/b)/a)**(-2)
```

The nice thing about this form is that you can substitute any values of `a,b,c` and get the corresponding value of `f`. Whether this is faster than using `nsolve`, you will have to see.

Comment: SymPy should really be able to do the change of variables in this case. It would take some investigation to see at what stage the process breaks with your equation.

Comment: Modifications given [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23253) allow the problem to be solved with less user-intervention.